# Vue material change icon color

Tags: css, material-design, vue-material

How do I change icon color for `<md-icon>`?
In Vue template I use it like this:

```
 <md-icon>list_alt</md-icon>
```

If I look in css rendered on the page I see the default color is grey defined in css as:

```
.md-icon.md-theme-default.md-icon-font {
    color: var(--md-theme-default-icon-on-background, rgba(0,0,0,0.54));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution is pretty simple:

```
<md-icon style="color:red">list_alt</md-icon>
```